# On Aquarius M10 Ubuntu Tablet— Tab-Complete with Virtual Keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, aquaris, bq

In the Terminal Application on the Aquarius M10, is there a capability similar to Tab-Complete when using the on-screen virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's sufficient to tap on the terminal window to send a TAB.

Answer (score 1):

You can swipe to the right on the console area and that will tab-complete. I assume it's sending a tab character.

Answer (score 1):

Added to the "swiping right" you can also find a TAB key within the terminal. You have to hold the layout icon (orange area on the bottom left here: [Terminal on Ubuntu Touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNS8v.png)) and select SCR. You'll get a selection of keys with tab amongst them.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to vi as command editor but Tab-complete works fine for me in the on-screen keyboard.

You have to switch to a different 'layout' as it is called in the keyboard/terminal settings. This is the white-on black ribbon above the keys and you can choose one with a TAB key by holding down the keypad symbol on the left side of the ribbbon and selecting "SCR".

Edit: I didn't know about the swipe or tap and that turns out to work just fine.