# On Ubuntu Tablet— Tab-Complete with Virtual Keyboard in any app?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, shortcut-keys, tablet

A similar question is asked at [On Aquarius M10 Ubuntu Tablet— Tab-Complete with Virtual Keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/q/763484/313406) , but it is referring exclusively to Terminal app.

I'm asking for any app, or at least for some browser. The intended use will be to run Ipython notebooks (Jupyter notebooks in general), however, without a tab key, I will lose tab completion.

Another possibility could be to install a virtual keyboard app with this ability (as hacker keyboard in Android) if it exists.